# ReactApplicationContext cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create a Native module for an Android SDK. When I try to pass reactContext to it I get the following `ReactApplicationContext cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity`. This is the block with error

```
try {
            manager.sendPaymentRequest(apiKey,
                                       hmac,
                                       txn,paymentCallback,reactContext);
        } catch (InvalidPaymentRequestException ipre){
            // Do something with the exception
            promise.reject("error ipre: "+ipre);
        } catch (Exception e){
            // Do something with the exception
            promise.reject("error e: "+e);
        }
```

I also tried passing `getCurrentActivity()` instead of `reactContext` but it gives `error: incompatible types: Activity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity` error. How can I pass AppCompatActivity in ReactNative. Also tried changing ReactNative MainActivity from ReactActivity to ReactFragment but there is no change. My React native version is 0.61.5 and Android API level is 28

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: No, and I think it is not possible so I went with another library to fulfill my use case.